# Is it possible to add a nested json "as is" in Go?

Tags: json, string, go, marshalling

Is this possible way to add nested json "as is". The nested json doesn't have any structure and might be different. I need to put the nested json data directly to the root node.

https://play.golang.org/p/MzBt7DLQEpD

```
type RootJson struct {
    NestedJson []byte
    AdditionalField string
}

func main() {
    nestedJson := []byte("{\"number\": 1, \"string\": \"string\", \"float\": 6.56}")

    rootJson := RootJson{nestedJson, "additionalField"}
    payload, _ := json.Marshal(&rootJson)

    fmt.Println(string(payload))

}
```

Comment: @Adrian I don't think that's a good idea to manipulate with JSON as a string

Comment: @Adrian: That obviously doesn't work. The JSON marshaling doesn't care how you "think" about strings.

Comment: It obviously *does* work. You can manipulate the totally normal string that JSON data is *after you've marshalled it*.

Comment: LOL. That's nothing like what you said. And anything but obvious. Also, an absolutely terrible answer to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use the [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) type which implements custom marshaling / unmarshaling, which "renders" it as-is into the JSON output. It's just a plain byte slice:

```
type RawMessage []byte
```

Its value should be the `UTF-8` encoded byte sequence of the raw JSON text (exactly what you get when you do a conversion, e.g. `[]byte("someText")`).

```
type RootJson struct {
    NestedJson      json.RawMessage
    AdditionalField string
}
```

With this, the output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/w7FxE6JwKTC)):

```
{"NestedJson":{"number":1,"string":"string","float":6.56},
    "AdditionalField":"additionalField"}
```

<sub>(Indentation added by me.)</sub>

Comment: Great! That’s what I need! Thanks!